# Accessing grid column values in VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, grid, getvalue

I am writing a chunk of code that takes a grid and does some processing.  In this processing, I need to look at a field in the grid that is a DateTime type.

I've seen two different techniques for accessing the field and I was wondering if there was any consensus on which might be better.  To be frank, I don't understand the syntax for the second one at all and haven't been able to find much of anything on it, but it's coming from someone who seems to know their onions and I wanted to see if it was much, much better, or if it was basically a draw.

So, what do you all think?

This one

```
d = (DateTime) row.Cells["DT0"].Value;
```

or this one?

```
d = row.Cells["DT0"].GetVal<DateTime>();
```

Or is there yet another, better, way?

Comment: `GetVal<T>()` ? Could you click in the middle of it and press F12 and tell me what Lib class this is comming from?

Comment: I think same behavior. You will get invalid type cast exception if your data type is different. For error handling, I always get value and try convert manually for avoiding exceptions.

Comment: xdtTransform - If you're asking if this is from a library we (or he) wrote, that would go a long way to explaining why I haven't been able to find anything on it. I saw this in code in our project that was written by someone else and didn't think it was in-house.  Are you saying that this might not be core C#? That would explain a lot!  Oh, and it says "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the carat" when I F12 right on "GetVal".

Comment: Based on my search, I only could find the first way to get datetime value. However, I suggest that you could do use DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["Time"].Value); to do it. As for the second method, I don't meet it, so I think it comes from other library.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it looks like the second one was an in-house thing after all.  Not sure why they did it as I have to move on and haven't had a chance to investigate it.

So it looks like the first one will do, providing I first check for

"if ( row.Cells[ "DT0" ].Value != null )"

Thank you all for your help!